# PHP 5.3.10 vs PHP 5.5.3 syntax error unexpected '['

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, dereference, php-5.5

Is it possible that this PHP code line

```
if ($this->greatestId()["num_rows"] > 0)
```

works in PHP 5.5 and returns an error in 5.3??

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/app/AppDAO.php on line 43
```

How can I change it to work under PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 15):

[Array dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) became available in PHP 5.4 That's why this doesn't work in PHP 5.3. So you have an extra step where you need to get the array value from your function call and then you can use it:

```
$variable = $this->greatestId();
if ($variable["num_rows"] > 0){
      // do stuff
}
```

Comment: found the link: https://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php inside new features they say: Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

Comment: I ran into this error yesterday, on my local env i have php5.5 and on testing 5.3 :/ thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use like this `if ($this->greatestId()["num_rows"] > 0)` in PHP 5.3 ver use below code.

```
$var = $this->greatestId();
if ($var["num_rows"] > 0){
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the PHP 5.4 notes:

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.

It's not possible to do that in PHP 5.3, you need to use a variable.